# Tradeoffs of using a join table vs type field

Tags: database-design

I'm looking insight into designing a database with a table which is related to multiple other tables.  A specific example is a site with comments on different kinds of the things - people could comment on articles, or they could comment on photos or they could comment on people.

It seems that there are two ways to represent this:

1) join tables for each other table
TABLES:

- articles
- articles_comments
- comments
- comments_people
- comments_photos
- people
- photos

or 
2)

- articles
- comments
- people
- photos

and the comment table will have a "type" field and a item_id to link back into the other table.

The first approach seems more "proper" and it seems we should have no problem using foreign key restraints whereas the second approach has fewer tables and might be "simpler" in some respect, but we can use FK restraints since the item_id can related to multiple FKs (AFAIK - using mysql innodb).  It might be good to not that in our application there might be 2-3 tables that have multiple relations (comments, photos, etc) and 5-10 tables that need relations.

I'm looking for advice on which is the better approach.

Comment: Approach #2 is terribly icky to manage manually. Have to track "source" and relationship key and no good way to setup relationship. If you are using a framework like Hibernate which supports subclasses via discriminated tables then it may be "workable" (e.g. never deal with it directly). However, I prefer #1 because it really does "fit the SQL model" better even if SQL DDL doesn't allow distributed keys to be nicely encoded :( [For the nitty-picky people, constraints and compound references can be used.]

Comment: note - after having lived and learned a little more, I changed the selected answer to the one from Yzmir Ramirez.  Having to deal with different comment table is much much worse in my opinion.  Changes in the concept of concepts have to be done in multiple places, deleting members requires searching through more tables and keeping track of them, also adding capabilities to the comment (eg attaching multiple media objects) becomes more complicated.

As an aside, I use views such as comment_people to make simple active record type ORMS easier to use - that "table" only has the single type in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `comment` table with the `type` column (an enum btw), seems like the better approach because you may want to evolve what a ''comment'' is in the future.

Having the four tables like you described it also lends itself to your Model class fields and  their relationships easier.

Use a 'LEFT JOIN' to the comments table if its a 0-to-many relationship.  Otherwise its an 'INNER JOIN'.

Enjoy.

Comment: thanks - what about the FK issues - would you just handle it in the code or with triggers?  Also, FWIW - I think with active record-type ORMs, they'll directly understand the the relationships with little/no configuration using the first approach the second will require a more sophisticated orm, I would think (or handling it manually)

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't like option #2. It represent what is a controversial topic, the ONE BIG LOOKUP TABLE Concept.

For one, I agree with Yzmir - icky to manage. Also, it represents the impostion of OO on the design of a relational database, which is a little like mixing apples and oranges. While it is easy for someone with an OO programming background (that includes ME . . . ) to imagine a "COmment Object" and it's properties, think for a moment about DB Design. The Tablenames in example 1 clearly desrcribe what is actually going on in both the entities they represent, and the relationships between them (the many-to-many reference tables). They also represent far better adherence to "Normal" form.

RBDMS is about representing entities and the relationships between them, and is not necessarily always consistent with the principles of OO. Further, the rules of normalization are more in favor of option #1.

Option #1, to me represents stronger RDB design, and is both easier to manage, more easily extensible, and will probably perform faster as well.